# How can I use Castle's RemotingFacility to access two different endpoints from the client?

Tags: .net, remoting, castle-windsor

I have a web application that communicates with multiple .net remoting endpoints.

I'd like to use the Castle RemotingFacility to resolve my remote dependencies, but it looks like you can only configure one endpoint uri for the facility.

Is this scenario possible with the existing RemotingFacility? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that really the case? I think that [this post](http://gojko.net/2008/07/09/really-simple-net-remoting-with-castle/) implies otherwise...

Comment: The RemotingFacility's remoteKernelUri can only be set to a single value. In the post you mentioned, that value is set to tcp://localhost:2133/kernel.rem. So, any remote type resolving goes through the remote registry located at localhost:2133. For my case, I need to be able to point to more than one remote registry. After reading through the remoting Facility and Inspector code, I don't think my case will work without some changes, but I'm game for any other suggestions.

Comment: OK, you're right. I misread your question. Can you bring this as suggestion to Castle-users group? We also accept patches :)